# Possible to view two text files side by side (read only)?

Tags: diff, text

In emacs, we can view two text files side by side.

Is it also possible to do so in some simpler/lighter applications such as `less`?

Only viewing, no editing.

Comment: Using `tmux` or `screen` makes this quite straightforward.

Comment: Do you need them to scroll in tandem? Why not just open two terminals with separate `less` commands? Does this need to be a command line program? When asking for tools, you need to be as specific as possible so we don't waste your and our time suggesting things that won't work for you.

Comment: @jasonwryan: that is a great solution. thanks

Answer (score 14):

The `less` command by itself cannot do any diff'ing. You can use the `diff -y` command to show the diff of 2 files side-by-side and then pipe that into `less` however.

#### Method #1 - using diff + less

This will create 2 sample files.

```
$ seq 100 > 1.txt
$ seq 10 100 > 2.txt
```

Now diff the 2 files:

```
$ diff -y 1.txt 2.txt | less
1                                                             <
2                                                             <
3                                                             <
4                                                             <
5                                                             <
6                                                             <
7                                                             <
8                                                             <
9                                                             <
10                                                              10
11                                                              11
12                                                              12
13                                                              13
...
```

#### Method #2 - using vimdiff

You can also use `vimdiff` in readonly mode, `-R`.

```
$ vimdiff -R 1.txt 2.txt
```

[image: ss #1]

#### Method #3 - using vim

If you truly just want to view 2 files side by side you can make use of `vim` like so to accomplish this:

```
$ vim -O +'windo set scrollbind' go.mod go.sum
```

For e.g.:

[image: ss1]

#### References

- [View two text files at the same time side by side](https://askubuntu.com/questions/722185/view-two-text-files-at-the-same-time-side-by-side)

Comment: how can I jump between different files?

Comment: @Thushi - how do you mean? Within vimdiff?

Comment: Yeah,Within vimdiff. If I have opened two files,lets say `a.txt` and `b.txt` then I want to switch between those two files.

Comment: Ctrl+w will switch b/w windows.

Comment: This shows a diff of the two files. This question is just about a side-by-side view.

Comment: @Timmmm - look again I show side by side diffs.

Comment: Yes exactly. The question is about just *viewing* two files side by side, not *diffing* them.

Comment: @Timmmm the Q has the tag `diff` on it.

Comment: @Timmmm added a 3rd method which does what you're asking.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure if it is possible using less command. However, it is possible using the below command. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341832/display-two-files-side-by-side),

```
pr -m -t one.txt two.txt
```

One more option that is useful though doesn't display side by side is,

```
tail -f file1 -f file2
```